# Separate implementation programming design

Tags: c#, java, design-patterns, jakarta-ee

I would like to have design suggestion for the following issue:

I am programming for server application.(JBOSS)

It's something very common, but I am not sure how to implement this.

I am implementing an Interface.

each class which implements that interface will have different implementation.

in the future, I am sure that I will need to add more implementations, which means I will need to add additional "new" to my code.

How can I separate the "new" allocations to  a different file/package/ear/jar, so if in the future I will have to add additional implementations for this specific interface, I wont need to open the whole source code.

I want to make it plug-ability, as much as I can.

thanks,

ray.

Comment: Coz architecture is cross platform.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're looking for [dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection).

Comment: The example in wiki, wasnt enough for me to understand, could you please pass me another example, so I could implement it in my code? thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you code to the interface instead of the implementation (which you should be doing anyway) then you can use dependency injection to specify the implementation details by configuration. This is a fairly common technique when using Spring.

When you later decide to use a new implementation, the implementing classes can be put in their own jar, added to your application and the dependency injection configuration can be changed.